# Return type of spring data projection

Tags: java, spring, projection

I am new to using Spring projections. So here's the problem I am having :
These are my domain class, projection, controller, Test method :

```
public class S{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String state;
    ...
}

public interface sProjection{
    public int getId();
    public int getName();
}

repository method : 
public List<sProjection> findByState(String state);

controller :
@GetMapping("/list")
public List<sProjection> scopeList(){
    List<sProjection> sThumbNailList = findByState("Protected")
    return sThumbNailList;
}

Test method :
@Test
public void testGet(){
    ResponseEntity<List<sProjection>> responseEntity = this.restTemplate.exchange("/webapi/s/list", HttpMethod.GET, null,  new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<sProjection>>() {});
}
```

The problem i am having is in the test method I am getting error saying since `sProjection` is an interface you can't instantiate it. Does anyone know what's the alternative to this ?
I tried using `List<Object> list` instead but `list.get` gets me a LinkedHashMap instead of a Object which I can cast to (sProjection). Anyone faced this problem before and figured out solution ?

Comment: Can you provide the actual stacktrace?

Comment: Spring data jpa behind the scenes is providing a proxy that wraps sProjection but the rest template is simply trying to construct a type based on the response type you're providing. Given sProjection is an interface is can't instantiate it

Comment: If you are talking about Spring data projections you need to define your repository as in [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)

`interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {

  NoAddresses findByFirstName(String firstName);
}`